# Project server: CreateWssSiteMessage failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

I'm getting this error since yesterday in a SharePoint 2013 / Project Server 2013 environment that was working just fine until this week:

> **GeneralQueueJobFailed (26000) - CreateWssSite.CreateWssSiteMessage. Detalles: id='26000' name='GeneralQueueJobFailed'
>   uid='9f19cb23-8e57-e511-811f-0050569b79e1'
>   JobUID='1fc14cb0-8d57-e511-811f-0050569b79e1'
>   ComputerName='bb117528-e4be-4ef0-ab78-25c5d2a6c508'
>   GroupType='CreateWssSite' MessageType='CreateWssSiteMessage'
>   MessageId='1' Stage=''
>   CorrelationUID='5b852c9d-b2c5-c08c-6c50-8cbb19352cc7'. ...**

And the ULS gives this error:

> **[QUEUE] CreateWssSiteMessage failed on Project e2c04cb0-8d57-e511-811f-0050569b79e1
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'PK_MSP_WEB_SECURITY_SP_CAT_RELATIONS_WSEC_REL_ID'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'pub.MSP_WEB_SECURITY_SP_CAT_RELATIONS'. The duplicate key value is
>   (9919cb23-8e57-e511-811f-0050569b79e1).  The statement has been
>   terminated. ...**

Any idea what is going on? 
I'm not (yet) crazy enough to customize a stored procedure of Project server to avoid the error...

Comment: are you trying to create new project instance?

Comment: Yes @WaqasSarwarMCSE, I was creating a new project instance, but now it works (see my answer below). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this PowerShell script in the internet and after executing it everything works as expected:

```
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null)
{
  Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
  Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}

Sync-SPProjectPermissions -Url "http://vmarsberge003:60200/PWA" -Type "Full"
```

Not very sure what was really happening but someway it's fixed now...